# Activating Add-In fails in Outlook for Web for the second appointment

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

#### Summary

When activating an addin (press add-in button to open sidepane) this currently only works for the first appointment opened from Outlook for Web. When closing the appointment and opening a new one it's not possible any more to activate a add-in.

#### Affected Add-Ins

After I discovered the issue with the Add-In I'm working on I was also successfully able to reproduce the same behavior with the OneNote Add-In. Therefore I'm pretty sure this is a general not Add-In related issue. On Friday the issue wasn't present. Our current Outlook script version seems to be 201910401.12.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Go to calendar view
2. Open new Appointment
3. Open Add-In with Sidepane
4. Close Appointment view
5. Open new Appointment
6. Try to open Add-In Sidepane
7. Observe that Sidepane does not open

#### Test Information

We verified this behavior on all tested environments:

- Windows + Edge
- Windows + Chrome
- Linux + Firefox
- Mac + Chrome

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. We are looking into this with high priority.

Comment: We pushed fix this in production. Is this still reproducible for you?

Comment: It's still reproducible for us (fresh browser instance new login). Do we need to do anything to update the account to the new version?

Comment: As of today the issue seems to have gone away.